# How align div vertical align div immediate following body tag

Tags: css

I want to align middle div tag. I set body and html height 100% and give div property `vertical-align: middle` but it wont work for me. I google it, most of the example they are using 2 div tag bug in my case I have to use only one div.

```
body, html { height:100%}    

<div style="vertical-align:middle; display:table-cell">middle</div>
```

Comment: Can you give us more code than this? What does your entire page contents look like?

Comment: @amit did you try **margin-top:auto** and **margin-bottom: auto**

Comment: @Adithya Did you try that yourself? According to [spec (10.6.3)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_heights_and_margins) for Block-level non-replaced elements `If 'margin-top', or 'margin-bottom' are 'auto', their used value is 0.`

Comment: @Adithya BTW, [`margin`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-margin) is not applicable to *table display types* elements.

Answer (score 1):

Better would be if you use two DIVs:
http://jsfiddle.net/Smr2y/

But here a solution with one DIV:
http://jsfiddle.net/M7Mpm/

```
body, html { height:100%; display:table;}

<div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">middle</div>
```